# How do I get first coordinates(lat long) from Json string

Tags: json, parsing, coordinates

I would like to set center of map dynamically using first coordinate from JSON string. How do I get first lat-long from below string?

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type": "Point","coordinates":[-120.341,50.6979]},"properties":{"ObjectType":"MyData","ObjectID":13,"ObjectName":"Kamloops"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type": "Point","coordinates":[-109.144,51.9373]},"properties":{"ObjectType":"LoadsNotMoving","ObjectID":114,"ObjectName":"Kerrobert"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type": "Point","coordinates":[-108.92,50.0435]},"properties":{"ObjectType":"LoadsNotMoving","ObjectID":147,"ObjectName":"Sidewood"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type": "Point","coordinates":[-119.435,50.8514]},"properties":{"ObjectType":"LoadsNotMoving","ObjectID":114,"ObjectName":"Notchhill"}}]}
```

Comment: Using what tool?

Answer (score 0):

In R, this is one way to achieve, "How to get first lat long from below string" can be done in the following way.  If you don't already have it, get / install the rjson package,   Then it's smooth sailing after that:

```
library(rjson)

# path on PC
jdata <- fromJSON(file = "C:/python/R_files/stackoverflow/test2.json")

df <- data.frame(jdata)    
df_coor <- df[4]                  
df_coor
```

Output:

```
A data.frame: 2 × 1
features.geometry.coordinates
<dbl>
-120.3410
50.6979
```

Let me know how things work out.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio and not sure How can I install rjson package. I am programming in JavaScript

Comment: Visual Studio or Visual-Studio Code ?  I quit using Visual Studio some years ago and replaced it with VS Code.  But most of the coding I do these days is using  R Studio and Jupyter Lab.  This code I provided is R code done in Jupyter.

Comment: There is no Visual Studio Code. Visual studio is editor to make web, window, mobile and other application

Comment: Do yourself a favor and become familiar with GIS before trying to do anything involving GIS with java/json/web.